# Is "around 100 last posts" natural?

Tags: phrase-usage

> "Interestingly, **around last 100 posts** seems to always from user A, B and C. Last 25 posts seems to always be from C."

Which one suits better in the example?

- Around 100 last posts
- Last around 100 posts
- Around last 100 posts

I think the confusion is that "around 100" and "last 100" are fixed phrases. So I can't come up a solution to combine the two together. Unfortunately, I'm unable to find the correct keyword to know about this.

Comment: What are you trying to say with this phrase?

Comment: "Interestingly, around last 100 posts seems to always from user A, B and C. Last 25 posts seems to always be from C."

Comment: "The latest 100 posts or so"

Comment: "The hundred latest" or "most recent" posts. (_Last_ can mean 'most recent', but it can also mean 'the last of a sequence' or 'the last there will ever be').

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it does not sound natural. It's a bit tricky to combine these two modifiers (*around* and *last*). Either one should be placed immediately before the "100", so there isn't room to use them both together.

I'd go with a phrase like

- roughly the last 100 posts
- the latest 100 posts or so
- the most recent 100 posts, more or less

Comment: +1 The version with "or so" is my choice